# select two properties in an array of obj

Tags: c#, linq, select

I've built an array of Invoice objects with properties Quantity, Price, PartDescription, and PartNumber:

```
Invoice[] invoices = {
        new Invoice( 83, "Electric sander", 7, 57.98M ),
        ...
        new Invoice( 3, "Wrench", 34, 7.5M ) }; // end initializer list
```

and I've successfully created two copies, sorted by PartDescription and Price by using the queries

```
IEnumerable<Invoice> invoicesByPartDescription = 
invoices.OrderBy(invoice => invoice.PartDescription);
```

and

```
IEnumerable<Invoice> invoicesByPrice =
invoices.OrderBy(invoice => invoice.Price);
```

So far, so good. However, when I attempt to make a third copy, but selecting for PartDescription and Quantity (and sorted by Quantity), I'm failing to get the correct syntax.

I've tried

```
IEnumerable<Invoice> invoicesSelPartDescription = 
invoices.Select(invoice => invoice.PartDescription)
.Select(invoice => invoice.Quantity)
.OrderBy(invoice => invoice.Quantity);
```

, but Visual Studio is throwing an error about the second Select, saying that there's no Quantity method defined.

I'd like to have an array that, when formatted for output, gives something like this:

```
{ PartDescription = Lawn mower, Quantity = 3 }
```

So I guess my question is: how can I use a Linq query to pare down the original array to only have two of its properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an [anonymous object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

```
var invoicesSelPartDescription = invoices
    .Select(invoice => new
        {
            invoice.PartDescription,
            invoice.Quantity
        })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Quantity);
```